# how to setup java rabbitMq asynchronous execution of process

Tags: java, asynchronous, rabbitmq

My Program Working in Synchronous way...I stored my msg using rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, (messageRequestXml));

In consumer ( Message receiver) it receives msg and processing it...
but till that time I am not getting response. Once I stored msg in queue..I need to send response to user without waiting for listener action.

Please help on this.

Comment: why are you using a MQ if you need it asynchronous? In this case rabbit is not really needed.

Comment: RabbitMQ works by default in an asynchronous way. That means that after using convertAndSend your program continues with its normal execution and it doesn't wait for any listeners to process the message (assuming the publisher/subscriber pattern).

Answer (score 0):

you may use DefaultConsumer, which is asynchronous consumer and will process newly added message immediately